# (Flutter Futurebuilder) the appbar title won't load as soon as the page changes

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-futurebuilder

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/login_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
String name;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

Future <void>loadPref()async{
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
    return name=sharedPreferences.getString("useFullName");
  });

}


logout()async{
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  sharedPreferences.clear();
  sharedPreferences.commit();
  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}


 var locationMessege= "";

  void getCurrentLocation()async{
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lastPosition=await Geolocator.getLastKnownPosition();
    print(lastPosition);

    setState(() {
      locationMessege="$position.latitude,$position.longitude";
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:Colors.orangeAccent,
        title: FutureBuilder(
          future: loadPref(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(name==null){
              return Text("Loading");
            }else{
              return Text("$name");
            }
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              logout();
            },
            child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/bg1.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                Column(
                  children:<Widget>  [
                    Container(
                        width: 130.0,
                        height: 130.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage("assets/solalogo2.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover))
                    ),
                    Text("GPS Location",style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    Icon(Icons.location_on,
                    size: 46,
                    color: Colors.yellow,),

                    Text("Position:$locationMessege",style:TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    FlatButton(onPressed:(){
                      getCurrentLocation();
                    },
                    color: Colors.orange,
                        child: Text("Get New Location",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),))
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After the successful login its being directed to to this home page. I want to load the users name on the `appbar` title, but it always trigger the loading statement and not load the name till I close the app and load it again. When you reopen the app you get directed to home page if the user previously logged in. I'm new to flutter and this has been my 2nd week working with it and any useful tips and advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: welcome, is it possible to take the username to homescreen after the user login?

Comment: Is it fit for your requirement.? Then it be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code of `loadPref()` method

```
Future <String> loadPref()async{
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await sharedPreferences.getString("useFullName");

}
```

---

```
        FutureBuilder(
          future: loadPref(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return Text("${snapshot.data}");
            }else{
              return Text("Loading");
            }
          },
        )
```

Comment: still the same, it only load if i quit and load the app again

Comment: Updating my answer, And this will definitely work Please try it and let me know

Comment: same issue ,now i have to close the app multiple times to get the name loading , for more clarification do you want FutureBuilder to go like this correct ?" title: FutureBuilder(....) "

Comment: What exactly are you doing to show title, I mean what is flow?

Comment: so first load it will check for the SharedPrefence for a token . if its null show the login screen if not pass to home screen. In the login screen as soon as the authentication is validate im sending another http request to collect user info from the api and save token and user info (User Full name , Id, Role ) in shared preference. Then in home screen im trying to show the the users full name on the app bar using the saved data in the SharedPreference

Comment: https://github.com/sudaraka93/FlutterApp i have uploaded the dart files to the github ,hope this will help you understand what i have done or trying to do .

Answer (score 1):

imho, using `FutureBuilder` for your case is a bit overkill.

You can use `then` method instead of using `await`. see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html.

So, change your `initState()` like the following code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String name = ""; // Defaulting to empty 
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((res) {
      setState(() {
        // Return string of "useFullName"
        // or return empty string if "userFullName" is null
        name = res.getString("useFullName")?? '';
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Now, you can simply using the `name` variable for your **AppBar** title:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor:Colors.orangeAccent,
      title: Text(name),
    ),

    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: im getting the red screen error on the ui saying "data!=null:null:A non-null Sting must be provided to a Text widget" even. when i set String name =" "; with a spacing as well

Comment: i dont know if its the redirect code after the validation of login is causing the problem , this is the code i use in a if statement to redirect to home screen " Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);"

Comment: That is because `res.getString("useFullName");` can return null. You need to check for it, something like `res.getString("useFullName")??"";`. See my edit.

Comment: same thing only when app is quit and re open it shows the name,  if it set to a condition to send black space it will return that instead of the actual data.

Comment: It's probably because SharedPreferences haven't finished saving the string yet when you  not `await`-ing the setString method. Try changing it to something like `await sharedPreferences.setString("useFullName",  "text");`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future <String> loadPref()async{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),()async{
  return await sharedPreferences.getString("useFullName");
});
```

}

wrapping the return with a delay made it work , but i have absolutely no idea why it worked now but not before and credit for Priyesh suggested code i modified that to get it running. and if any one know why it didn't work please do let me know! thank you .